# Drop variables if mean is 0 for loop

Tags: stata

I want to `drop` all variables that have a mean of 0. The code I'm using is

```
foreach var of varlist _all {
    drop 'var' if mean 'var'==0
}
```

and I'm getting the error message `mean not found`.

How can I get around this?

Comment: Stata is so spelled. https://www.statalist.org/forums/help#spelling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several reasons why that won't work. First, consider this suggested solution:

```
foreach var of varlist _all {
    su `var', meanonly 
    if r(mean) == 0 drop `var' 
}
```

This will work with string variables too, as the request to `summarize` a string variable isn't illegal, and the mean will be returned as missing.

What's wrong with your code?

Problem 1. The sequence

```
mean `var' == 0
```

is just fantasy syntax. There isn't a mean function that you can apply in this context and if there were, the syntax would be different.

Problem 2. You can `drop` observations using an `if` qualifier or you can `drop` variables but you can't mix syntaxes. It's hard even to know what the mix would mean, but it's illegal any way. The deeper problem here is confusing the `if` command and the `if` qualifier. See also the `help` for `drop`.

Problem 3. As typed here you have used matching quotation marks for local macro references. It's possible to guess that you really used left and right quotation marks as otherwise you would have got a different error message. Nevertheless, your code as typed would not work for that reason also.

A wider comment is a reminder that a mean of zero doesn't imply that all values of zero. If you wanted just to `drop` variables with all values zero, then `findname` (*Stata Journal*) allows that

```
findname, all(@ == 0)
drop `r(varlist)'
```

and there are extensions to allow missing values too.